# LG (with Android > 2.1) media player don't play shoutcast stream

Tags: android, audio, stream, media-player, shoutcast

I'm writing an android app for play shoutcast stream for a publisher that implements web radio.

On API level 8 (android 2.2) MediaPlayer class can play stream, so:

```
Uri myUri = ....; // initialize Uri here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

In real app i'm using prepareasync() so UI is responsive for a ProgressDialog.

But for this example prepare() is ok.

Now... 
on Android < 2.2 (API level < 8) mediaplayer don't play.
on Android >= 2.2 (API level >= 8) mediaplayer play, but not on all device.

This code work on:

Nexus One (CyanogenMod 7, Android 2.3.x)
Samsung Galaxy S (Stock Rom, Android 2.3.x)
Samsung Galaxy S 2 (Stock Rom, Android 2.3.x)
HTC Desire (Stock Rom, Android 2.3.x)
HTC Desire HD (Stock Rom, Android 2.3.x)
Emulator (Android 2.2)
Asus eee Pad Transformer TF101 (Stock Rom, Android 4.0.3)

This code don't work on every LG devices with Android > 2.2...
but... why?

How can I play shoutcast strem on LG devices?

Comment: You're going to need to narrow this problem down if you expect any useful help.  Do a packet trace.  Is the connection to the server getting made?  Is data being transferred?  Is it just not decoding properly?  Is metadata disabled?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem with LG phones and shoutcast.  It gets to prepare() and then throws an error for the media player has crashed.  I looked on LG's site but could not find any documentation or developer areas for help from them.  Has anyone figured out what LG is doing different and how to make it work??